# ArgumentError: The scope body needs to be callable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have the following methods defined in a plugin:

```
class ReArtifactProperties < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable

  #attr_accessible :artifact_type

  scope :without_projects, :conditions => ["artifact_type != ?", 'Project']
  scope :of_project, lambda { |project|
    project_id = (project.is_a? Project) ? project.id : project
    {:conditions => {:project_id => project_id}}
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Copy them to your question, that others with the same problem can find them.

Comment: sorry sir. the error is as follows                                                     SyntaxError: C:/Sites/redmine/plugins/redmine_re/app/models/re_artifact_properti
es.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'
{ |project|
   ^
C:/Sites/redmine/plugins/redmine_re/app/models/re_artifact_properties.rb:11: syn
tax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end

Comment: Copy them to your question, that others with the same problem can find them.

Comment: Are you sure you are meeting rails and redime requireemnts?

Comment: i am using windows 7 to run both redmine and ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several issues, some of which are violations of syntax rules of Ruby, while others violate return value requirements of Rails.

The cause of your current error is a syntax error. The block to the lambda must be defined in the same line as the `lambda` method.

Now, if you have fixed this, you will notice that your code will throw other exceptions once you use the scope. The reason for that is that the return value of a scope is expected to be an ActiveRecord relation, not just a simple Hash.

Your scope definition should thus look similar to this:

```
scope :of_project, lambda { |project|
  project_id = (project.is_a? Project) ? project.id : project
  where(:project_id => project_id)
}
```

Now given that Rails is smart enough to figure out how to get the ID from an object for a query, you can even get rid of the `project_id` logic in it and reduce your scope definition to

```
scope :of_project, lambda { |project|
  where(:project_id => project)
}
```

Comment: Changes were done as said but still the arguement error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

> Your code has several issues, some of which are violations of syntax rules of Ruby, while others violate return value requirements of Rails.

Yes you were right about the lambda block

Initially the code was:

```
scope :of_project, lambda { |project|
    project_id = (project.is_a? Project) ? project.id : project
    {:conditions => {:project_id => project_id}}
  }
```

After Correction, it reduced down to this:

```
scope :of_project, lambda { |project|
  project_id = (project.is_a? Project) ? project.id : project
  where(:project_id => project_id)
}
```

> Now given that Rails is smart enough to figure out how to get the ID from an    object for a query,

Knowing the MVC architecture which I learned from

http://rubyonrails.org/

How do I understand the core functions of RAILS w.r.t Redmine Tool?The mysql default database that it uses has a very huge model structure currently.Could it be reduced down to understand the core functions of Rails?